# ngrx effects not getting data from api on first hit

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular-ngrx-data

Hi so below is my component code where save function has validateData() which has call to api and after the call in store.select is called but not getting the response on the first hit its getting update on second hit and navigatetonext() function takes the response so first time its taking empty object and for second hit it is getting resp if write nagigatetonext funtion inside store.select its getting called multiple times.

```
    save(){
    this.cpCommonService.clearErrorDivs();
 // this.spinner.show();
    if(this.router.url === '/test/details'){
       this.ethnicityData();
    }else if(this.router.url === '/test/details/member_name'){
      this.navigationPath.componentName = "member_name";
      this.validateData();
    }else{
      // this.navigationPath.componentName = "member_ssn";
      this.ssnData();
    }


    this.store.select('data').subscribe(data => {
      this.currentPageData = data;
      this.isNextClicked = false;

    });
     this.nextPage(this.currentPageData);
    this.store.dispatch(new TestActions.UpdateMembersForm(this.currentPageData['membersForm']['value']));
  }

    GetPostData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
         ofType<TestActions.PostData>(TestActions.POST_DATA),
         mergeMap(action =>
        this.byhService.navigationDetails(action.payload).pipe(map(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
            return new TestActions.PostDataSuccess(resp);
        }, catchError((error) => of(new TestActions.PostDataError(error))))
        )

    )
)
```

Comment: Can you post your code more simplified i.e. effects, service and component codes separately

Comment: where are you dispatching PostData action?

Comment: @Umesh https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8lgts this is sample how my component and store looks dispatch called at valdiatedata in household component

Comment: @AnandBhushan hi added https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8lgts sample component and store looks like this

Comment: @Umesh http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8lgts

Answer (score 0):

`GetPostData$` isn't marked as an effect with either @Effect or createEffect.

The actions won't dispatch.